# How to use log4j2 in the web application WITHOUT log4j-web.jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to put the configuration file of the log4j2 (v2.17.0) outside of the war file. Therefore, I can change the logging configuration without redeploying the war file. The [log4j2-web.jar](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) provides mechanism to configure the configuration file outside of the war file along with other features.

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use the log4j-web.jar file in web application.
According to the log4j2 [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_from_code), it is not recommended to use LoggerContext to load configuration file because it is not part of the public API.

Question:
Is there any valid way to use log4j2 in the web application without log4j-web.jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Is there any valid way to use log4j2 in the web application without log4j-web.jar file?

There are two potential ways that you could dynamically update the logging configs without using log4j2-web.jar .

1. Ignore the FAQ's recommendation<sup>1</sup> and use `LoggerContext.reload` to reload the configuration.

   It is possible that the Log4j2 team could change something in a future version so that this approach no longer works. But this is unlikely (IMO) ... and you can deal with that problem if / when it happens.
2. Use Log4j2's [automatic reconfiguration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration) mechanism.  Basically, you tell Log4j2 to regularly check the config file to see if it has changed.

---

However ...

If I was you, I would want to understand **why** you are "not allowed" to use "log4j-web.jar".  Is it for security reasons?  If it is, you may need to talk to the security people so that you fully understand the security reasons.

Q: Why?

A: Because you appear to be wanting to duplicate some of the functionality of "log4j-web.jar".  It may be that it is the functionality you are trying to duplicate that is the root of your security team's concerns.  And if that is the case, then implementing the functionality by hand (i.e. without using "log4j-web.jar") could potentially be worse ... from a security perspective!

So ... find out!  This is NOT a case where "asking for forgiveness rather than for permission" is a sound strategy.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, I don't read this as a "recommendation".  Rather, I read it as a "warning of potential consequences".  If they really thought that using `LoggerContext.reload` this was a bad idea, I think they would have used more explicit language.</sup>